# Spring boot custom server

Tags: json, spring-boot, tomcat, console

I started using SpringBoot and like it a lot. I see that @RestController automatically serializes POJOs to json. I like that functioonality, but would like to use it outside of a web server context.
Basically I'd like to have all the part of SpringBoot until the point where the response is in JSON format, but then I don't want to deliver it via a web server, but rather my own implementation.

Is there an interface I have to implement in order to get SpringBoot to accept non-web-requests and return non-web-responses.

An example to make clear what I want:
Right now I can access localhost:8080/hello and SpringBoot will return "world".
Is there a way to make this work on console. E.g. I enter "hello" on console and press enter and I get "world" delivered to console by SpringBoot.
So instead of a web interface via tomcat I'd like to implement a console interface but with the same SpringBoot functionality.

UPDATE: The console application was probably not the right example. I am looking for a more general approach. So let's say instead of a console interface I want an Arduino to be able to send "hello" to SpringBoot via a serial bluetooth connection and SpringBoot should return "world" on that same bluetooth serial connection. My question is, whether there is an interface I need to implement in order to tell SpringBoot how to accept REST requests and how to send responses. And I don't want to focus on a particular implementation (like console or BT serial), but instead, once the SpringBoot application is created, I'd like to just replace the tomcat web interface by a BT serial interface or a console interface or any other interface I want to implement, but keep all of the logic (Controllers, Models etc).

Thanks.

Comment: Still not clear for me. You say you want your SB app to accept REST requests. This has to be via HTTP interface. Maybe this is more an architectural question. And you want to have a Producer - Consumer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You can create a console application.

You will need to create a class that implements ConsoleRunner. Please find a tutorial here:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app

Answer (score 0):

If it is the JSON de/serialization that interests you. 
You can use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)'s [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) .
You don't need the whole spring-boot web stuff.

You can ommit the starter-web dependency and use [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html) and jackson to have a console application that de/serializes your responses/requests to json.